# Internal sandstone mortar under sash window

Tags: walls, insulation, windows, old-house

Whilst re-decorating a sash window I, perhaps unwisely, removed a wooden board below the window to find exposed mortar (see photo). The mortar is crumbling and flakey. The external walls are sandstone. This is a Victorian first floor flat in Glasgow, Scotland.

1. What is the mortar substance?
2. Is it advisable to repair this, if so how?
3. Should I attempt to insulate the cavity, or just box it back up with a wooden board?

[image: Sash window with lower panel removed]

Comment: You broke it, you fix it :P

Comment: Where is this house? Different materials were used depending on where you were.

Comment: The house is in Glasgow, Scotland